# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-configuration

I've mvc web project and I have added another empty project which holds all the services more like repository.

So I'm having issue where it throws error and I can't figure it out why even though I have added bindings in Web.config.

**Error:**

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'DataService.ISDService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

**App.config:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SDEndPoint" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://services.local.com/Api.svc/wsHttp"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SDEndPoint"
                contract="ImageService.ISDService" name="SDEndPoint">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="nyc\pc" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Web.config:**

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://services.local.com/Api.svc/wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SDEndPoint" contract="ImageService.ISDService" name="SDEndPoint">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="nyc\pc" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
</client>
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: > I've mvc web project and I have added another empty project which holds all the services more like repository Are you consuming them or hosting them in the new empty project ? If you are hosting them , does it need to be Startup Project ?

Comment: Are you able to browse to `http://services.local.com/Api.svc/wsHttp` in a web browser?  If so, what do you see?

Comment: i've reference the project into my web (dll's) and my start up project is Web

Comment: Are you using your "repository" to consume WCF hosted elsewhere ?

Comment: yes service works fine. i crated a test project and im able to connect from test.

Comment: yes, so i've added service reference in repository and then im calling that repository from website  to handle data. but it throws error.

Comment: Ok, you are using your "repository" as WCF  client.You may need to add app.config file to your repository project.                                                                                                                     You can use the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) client configuration to specify the address, binding, behavior, and contract, the "ABC" properties of the client endpoint, which clients use to connect to service endpoints. The <client> element has an <endpoint> element whose attributes are used to configure the endpoint ABCs.

Comment: This will go into app.config in your repository.                                        <client>
      <endpoint address="http://services.local.com/Api.svc/wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SDEndPoint" contract="ImageService.ISDService" name="SDEndPoint">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="nyc\pc" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
</client>

Comment: Also your error message has 'DataService.ISDService' and your app and web config has contract="ImageService.ISDService" . Please double check names

Comment: I have bindings in app config containing the reference and same reference are in web.config but when debugging in repository it throws error complaining about could not find binding. The names are 100% same as i copied from app config.

Comment: In your web.config file is your client configuration inside  <system.serviceModel>  </system.serviceModel> ? like in app.config .In the question it does not seem that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move everything down to the Web.config in order for this to work, because it's the web app that is hosting the service.

Comment: the service is hosted else where, im referencing that service in my repository project and website simple calling that repository which is part of the web project.

Comment: @CodeBox It's the same whether you are talking about hosting a service or a client actually. Unfortunately you can't split your WCF configuration across multiple libraries. You need to have all of your config-based WCF configuration in the Web.config of your application, since that's what's actually going to be managing your client and providing a context for it.

Answer (score 0):

The solve your problem, the calling project needs to have the the same configuration for the services. Just copy the `<System.ServiecModel />` part into your website Webconfig. Also, you may need to copy the same settings in the repository.